# Why is the type here deduced to be uint32_t?

Tags: c++, c++11, type-deduction

The following code is deducing the auto to uint32_t. I am trying to understand why it is so.

```
auto value = a + b * c;
```

where a is int32_t, b is uint32_t and c is int.

Comment: `uint32_t` has higher conversion rank than `int32_t`, and (on your system) `int`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Type conversion rules are a bit weird sometimes.
Every type is given a rank, but every platform can implement the conversions as it fits them, with generally only few rules.

[securecoding](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/c/INT02-C.+Understand+integer+conversion+rules) has a nice wrap up:

> Integer Conversion Rank
>
> Every integer type has an integer conversion rank that determines how
>   conversions are performed. The ranking is based on the concept that
>   each integer type contains at least as many bits as the types ranked
>   below it. The following rules for determining integer conversion rank
>   are defined in the C Standard, subclause 6.3.1.1 [ISO/IEC 9899:2011]:
>
> - No two signed integer types shall have the same rank, even if they have the same representation.
> - The rank of a signed integer type shall be greater than the rank of any signed integer type with less precision.
> - The rank of long long int shall be greater than the rank of long int, which shall be greater than the rank of int, which shall be
>     greater than the rank of short int, which shall be greater than the
>     rank of signed char.
> - The rank of any unsigned integer type shall equal the rank of the corresponding signed integer type, if any.
> - The rank of any standard integer type shall be greater than the rank of any extended integer type with the same width.
> - The rank of char shall equal the rank of signed char and unsigned char.
> - The rank of _Bool shall be less than the rank of all other standard integer types.
> - The rank of any enumerated type shall equal the rank of the compatible integer type.
> - The rank of any extended signed integer type relative to another extended signed integer type with the same precision is
>     implementation-defined but still subject to the other rules for
>     determining the integer conversion rank.
> - For all integer types T1, T2, and T3, if T1 has greater rank than T2 and T2 has greater rank than T3, then T1 has greater rank than T3.
>
> The integer conversion rank is used in the usual arithmetic
>   conversions to determine what conversions need to take place to
>   support an operation on mixed integer types.

Comment: A short summary, how the cited rules apply to the formula in the question and yield the observed result would improve the answer.

Comment: Oh and you are citing the C standard for a c++ question.